# Add single parent node by selecting multiple elements in D3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I have problem where I have to add a parent node by selection of multiple elements.

I have:

```
<g class="group">
     <g class="Node" id="1">...</g>
     <g class="Node" id="2">...</g>
     <g class="Node" id="3">...</g>
     <g class="Node" id="4">...</g>
</g>
```

Now in the above structure i have to select some elements which have class `Node` by their ids and add a parent single parent element for them.

It should look something like this, if I select Node 2 & 3 for example:

```
<g class="group">
    <g class="Node" id="1">...</g>
    <g class="Grp">
        <g class="Node" id="2">...</g>
        <g class="Node" id="3">...</g>
    </g>
    <g class="Node" id="4">...</g>
</g>
```

Is there some way I can do this manipulation by using javascript or D3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for completeness, this is (one of...) the idiomatic D3 for doing that:

```
var group = d3.select(".group");
var newGroup = group.insert("g", "#g2").attr("class", "Grp");
var nodes = group.selectAll("#g2, #g3").remove();
nodes.each(function() {
  var self = this;
  newGroup.append(function() {
    return self
  });
});
```

The nice thing about `remove()` method is that, like several methods in D3, it returns the selection. Therefore, we can remove the elements but keeping a reference to them, so we can append them later (inside the new group).

Here is the demo. Nothing will show up in the SVG (painted in blue), you have to inspect the SVG using your browser's web inspector to see the groups structure:

```js
var group = d3.select(".group");
var newGroup = group.insert("g", "#g2").attr("class", "Grp");
var nodes = group.selectAll("#g2, #g3").remove();
nodes.each(function() {
  var self = this;
  newGroup.append(function() {
    return self
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg style="background-color:powderblue;">
  <g class="group">
     <g class="Node" id="g1"></g>
     <g class="Node" id="g2"></g>
     <g class="Node" id="g3"></g>
     <g class="Node" id="g4"></g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

With javascript you can do something like this

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll('.group, #id2, #id3'); // grab the parent and id2/3
var grp = document.createElement('g');                     // create wrapper
grp.className = 'Grp';                                     // give it a class
els[0].insertBefore(grp, els[1]);                          // insert it before id2
grp.appendChild(els[1]);                                   // move id2 to wrapper
grp.appendChild(els[2]);                                   // move id3 to wrapper
```

```css
.Grp {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<g class="group">
  <g class="Node" id="id1">.1.</g>
  <g class="Node" id="id2">.2.</g>
  <g class="Node" id="id3">.3.</g>
  <g class="Node" id="id4">.4.</g>
</g>
```

Comment: Thanks, working fine for grouping. But looks like when I create SVG elements using createElement, it is not treated as svg element and does not show up. As g is a SVG container, I had to use: document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g")

Comment: @VishalAsh This works just fine with an SVG-container as well, though to see the actual grouping, use the browsers "Inspect" tool.

Comment: I should have mentioned that g is SVG element.

Comment: @VishalAsh Yepp, you should :) ... and since you use D3 you might wanna go with Gerardo's answer anyway to avoid any cross browser issues

Comment: @LGSon I reckon OP should keep your answer as accepted. First, he said *"by using javascript OR d3"*. Second, even D3 programmers use pure JS for a case like this.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thanks for that info (and plus 1 for your answer). I don't use D3, though guessed they do use plain js once in a while, hence posted this answer. I still think going with a D3 version might be safer, though can't for mentioned reason say more, and targeting SVG can have its challenges cross browser :)

Comment: For me createElement was creating an SVG element with zero width and zero height and was not showing up as the g elements had svg rect inside them. Thanks for both the answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are easy, you can do it with `jQuery`. Less lines of code.

```js
$( "#2, #3" ).wrapAll( "<div class='Grp'></div>" );

console.log($(".group").html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<g class="group">
     <g class="Node" id="1">...</g>
     <g class="Node" id="2">...</g>
     <g class="Node" id="3">...</g>
     <g class="Node" id="4">...</g>
</g>
```